# The site stopped working. syntax error

Tags: php, html

Good afternoon! Today the site stopped working:

error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/smuer/smuer.ru/docs/templates/jp_business/index.php on line 120

[index.php on google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ZDBv_VUVaXaXRrNVE2TEJ4bzA)

Help pls

Comment: That means you have a syntax error. Read your code carefully around this line and you should find your bug.

Comment: The problem is that the code is not mine. There is no backup copy of the site, there is nothing to compare it with.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the previous line. You're probably missing a ) or a ; that's all!